# ServiceStack cant handle cookie from subdomain angular client

Tags: angularjs, cookies, localization, servicestack

I have a problem on servicestack catch client cookie.
My Service domain : service.domain.com
Website (Angular) : www.domain.com
Each one on dedicated server.
I developing on Self-Host method in Servicestack 4.
Here is my Request Filter looks cookies than if noting than set thread culture.

```
  this.PreRequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp) =>
        {

            var lang = httpReq.GetCookieValue("Lang");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang))
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);    
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
                httpResp.SetCookie("Lang","en",TimeSpan.FromDays(100));

            }

        });
```

and this is my Language service taking "Lang" parameter.

```
    public class LanguageService : ServiceStack.Service
{
    public Language Any(LanguageRequest request)
    {
        this.Response.SetCookie("Lang", request.Lang, TimeSpan.FromDays(100));
        return new Language() { };
    }
}
```

Unfortunalety prerequestfilter catch noting after languageservice.
Thanks for your suggestions.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Cookies in different sub domains are treated as separate domains.

You can try specifying the domain on each Cookie with:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    RestrictAllCookiesToDomain = "domain.com",
});
```